# Android: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: android, user-permissions

Some of my app users are seeing the "Permission denied" exception

Specially for the following device: **`Xiaomi MI MAX Android OS: 7.0`**

Other devices are able to access Internet.

I've added the required permissions before the application tag, like this,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application>
...
</application>
```

Can anyone please help what is wrong here?

Comment: For marshmallow permission please check https://inducesmile.com/android/android-6-marshmallow-runtime-permissions-request-example/

Comment: I also have that type of crash logs happening only on Xiaomi devices and mainly on background works. Did you find something?

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6.0 and above, there is a new way of requesting permission from the user, which is called runtime permission, which means permission is granted when the app is running, not when it is installed like earlier versions.
Check the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for complete explanation

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) it's not.

Comment: My bad, @Ch4t4r is on point there. Either way, have you tried to check if the device actually grants permission using checkSelfPermission() method?